EF Core, one to many relationship, one table referencing multiple tables
In attempt to reduce the number of tables in a database, I'd like to use a single table to store the same type of data for multiple reference tables: a one to many relationship several times over with a single foreign table.
public class Note
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}

public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}

Using Code First, I've attempted OnModelCreating for Article and Order entities:
        builder.HasMany(h => h.Notes)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.ParentId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

and I get an exception when saving changes:

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException : An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
----> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException : SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'.

Is what I am trying to accomplish possible with EF Core 8?
I would like to avoid creating multiple foreign key columns (parent1id, parent2id, etc..) each for separate parent table.. and intermediate/linking table also seems redundant..

This is called polymorphic associations and it's considered an anti-pattern. Just add a notes table per entity. The database isn't scared of "many" tables and it offers more opportunities for query optimization.

This model is very confusing which should be a big red warning flag. FK constraints are constraints, not relations. If you specify this FK constraint for both Article and Order, you're actually saying that a new Note must always have a related row in both Article and Order. That rarely makes sense. In Notes that do have rows in both tables, DeleteBehavior.Cascade will fail because both the Order and Article row will have to be deleted. Otherwise deleting a note due to an Article deletion will be blocked by the Order FK

You will run into problems with the suggested structure.
Note references an Order or Article by ID.
Imagine you have an Article with ID 1 and an Order with ID 1 and a Note with ParentId = 1
Which object (Article or Order) does the Note belong to? It cannot be said.

the ID is a GUID so this should not be a problem. Also in other RDBMS such as oracle there is a concept of sequence which should also guarantee ID uniqueness even with integers. So the only problem I see is EF's support for this kind of structure..

sorry I now realize that in my example I have used an Int as an ID :) but, let's suppose it's a GUID which is unique in 99,999 of times. what's the problem? :)

accepting the answer, but still not convinced that this should be an issue. Technically:

step. use Guids for Ids
step. create index on parentId column in children table.
step. Select * from parents1/2/3 left join children on parentsX.id = children.parentId
4, profit
there is no need to create foreign keys that cause the constrain errors..


One foreign key field is meant to reference one table.

public class Note
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? ArticleId { get; set; }
    public Article? Article { get; set; }

    public int? OrderId { get; set; }
    public Order? Order { get; set; }
}

public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}

On Model Creating:
 builder.Entity<Article>
     .HasMany(x => x.Notes)
     .WithOne(x => x.Article)
     .HasForeignKey(x => x.ArticleId)
     .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

 builder.Entity<Order>
     .HasMany(x => x.Notes)
     .WithOne(x => x.Order)
     .HasForeignKey(x => x.OrderId)
     .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

